# Как сделать так, чтобы данные отображались в трёх столбиках и сортировались по дате по возрастанию по столбикам?

Tags: c#, bootstrap, циклы, сортировка

На данный момент у меня в цикле foreach прописан класс col-sm-4, который делит данные на 3 столбика, сортировка в которых происходит по строчкам, а надо чтобы по столбикам.
Например, сейчас это выглядит так:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

А надо чтобы было так:

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

Понимаю, что нужно использовать Count, но вот как это записать?
Код:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in items) {
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="">
          <a href"" target="_self">
            <span class="date"> @(item.Date)</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<items.Count; i+=3)`